# Питон чтение и запись из файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, txt

У меня есть txt файл в котором есть слова разделённые запятой после запятой пробел как на python записать все эти слова поместить в список?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
output = []

with open("some_name.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    for line in f:
        output += line.strip().split(", ")
```

---

*Примечание:*

Когда ваш файл в другой кодировке, нужно вместо `utf-8` применить другую, вероятно `windows-1251` для русских текстов.

---

*Объяснение:*

- метод `.strip()` убирает пустые символы перед/за, в том числе и символ `\n` перехода на новую строку, который в конце каждой строки в водном файле,
- метод `.split(", ")` затем разбивает строку на отдельные слова и сделает из них список слов
- в цикле `for` этот список добавим к существующему (сначала пустому).

Answer (score 4):

```
def f(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        return file.read().split(', ')
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете использовать стандартный модуль [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

with open("some_name.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    output = [word.strip() for line in csv.reader(f) for word in line]
```